# How would I go about editing the Gnome-shell launcher GRID, to have more columns/rows?

Tags: linux, x11, gnome3, gnome-shell, wayland

[image]

Having a 21:9 ratio resolution, it seems like it's a lot of wasted space!?

Comment: there is a extension for this.. I will share u the link

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1044469/739431